# Xcode 4.1 - location prompt in iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

The app I'm working on uses CLLocationManager, and previously, when the app starts asking for location info in the iPhone simulator, I would get a little popup.

Yesterday I installed Xcode 4.1, and now I no longer get the prompt. My app also never gets any location information, and times out every time.

Anyone know what I should check or where to start figuring this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not alone, seems to be a problem with the iPhone Simulator in Lion & Xcode 4.1, https://devforums.apple.com/message/491549